# Code share Includes folder outside protected folder in IIS8

Tags: iis, asp-classic, passwords

Network solutions just migrated our classic ASP IIS web site to Windows 2012 and a password protected folder is now failing with a 401 error. I have been informed that the includes folder referenced OUTSIDE the password protected folder is now impossible. This can't be true as I would have to maintain two copies of the includes files: 1 outside in the public space and 1 inside the password protected folder. Doesn't code share allow this to work?

Comment: I don't see how your include files could be causing the 401 errors. Those errors indicate permission problems with the main asp files. Can you elaborate?

Comment: If a folder that is password protected references a file outside that folder IIs 8.x will error. For example an includes file outside the folder that is referenced by a file *inside* the password protected folder.